# Database model for rent virtual goods

Tags: database, modeling

I have a database modeling related problem and would like you guys to give me sugestions how could i solve it.

I need to sell "virtual services". I made some tables: Clients, Services, Order, OrderLine. So a Order can contains multiples services. Each service has an "contract time". If i order a service it is valid for 30 days then i need to order it again if i want to continue using it. if i order a service for 30 days and 10 days has passed i still have 20 days. If i order it again i'll have 50 days.

How can i model the database to control this?

Comment: Sounds like you're modeling it just fine.  But this isn't really much of a question.  So keep it up and come back when you have a concrete problem either with your design or your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to use Orderline and have the start date and end date valid for that particular order.

So you will have one entry for every renewal. And this table should have FKs to Service and Order.

Comment: Looks good. So if the client buys 2 services in an Order will have to add two entries for that Order right? And everytime i add an entry i should verify if there's one "active" and set the start date from the next entry to the end of the "active".

Comment: do i really need a table called ServiceEntry? I could add start date and end date to orderlines. Do you see any problems in that?

Comment: Ah sorry, I think orderline == ServiceEntry. You dont need extra one. I ll change my post.